# Laravel 5.6 - Permission denied when trying to retrieve image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.6 project running on a Windows Bitnami WAMP stack. I am storing an image like this..

```
$imageName = myfile.jpg
$path = $request->file->storeAs('images', $imageName);
```

This works and the file is correctly stored, I am trying to retrieve it like this..

$source = Storage::get('images', $imageName);

But I get the error message...

```
file_get_contents(C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.18-1\apache2\htdocs\myproject\storage\app\images): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

This looks like a permissions issue, the storage\app\images folder looks like this

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 win_user 192142 0 Jul  2 18:15 images
```

Anyone any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Make sure the whole `storage` folder has the correct permissions

Comment: Have confirmed 0755 permissions on storage folder and all subfolders

Comment: `755` is supposed to be for folders and `644` for files

Comment: Correct, both are set correctly

Comment: Who owns the file (image) that gets stored?

Comment: Make sure permission is recursive. Add **-R** while setting permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_get_contents(C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.18-1\apache2\htdocs\myproject\storage\app\images): failed to open stream: Permission denied

you are save the file to default local disk, check your config/filesystems.php

default local disk is not allow access by url

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

oops, my mistake, you are get the file, not display the image by url

try `$source = Storage::get('images/' . $imageName);`

Comment: I have checked the filesystems.php and it looks exactly as above

Comment: try $source = Storage::get('images/' . $imageName);

Answer (score 0):

It's permission issue. Execute the following commands in the parent directory of your document root.

> Please note that `public_html` is not a `public` directory of the laravel project. It's the parent directory.

**For Ubuntu:**

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public_html
```

**For centOS**

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache public_html
```

In case your web server does not have permissions to write a file, executing these commands will solve the issue. Let me know if it helps.